# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectName' - wsgi Django Deployment

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run my Django Project using Apache.

When I launch Apache I receive an 'Internal Server Error', inspecting the logs I have found that it fails to execute the wsgi.py for my project and throws the errors below.

The error presented says there is `No module named 'localassets'`, i.e. the projectname.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5128): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/Env/localassets/localassets/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost/
mod_wsgi (pid=5128): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Env/localassets/localassets/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost/
Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:/Env/localassets/localassets/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost/
     application = get_wsgi_application()\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Env\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://localhost/
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Env\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r, referer: http://localhost/
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Env\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__\r, referer: http://localhost/
    self._setup(name)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Env\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup\r, referer: http://localhost/
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Env\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__\r, referer: http://localhost/
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r, referer: http://localhost/
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load\r, referer: http://localhost/
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r, referer: http://localhost/
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localassets'\r, referer: http://localhost/
```

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/Python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Env/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Program Files/Python310"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Env/localassets/localassets/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Env/Lib/site-packages"

<Directory "C:/Env/localassets/localassets/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "C:/Env/localassets/localassets/static"
<Directory "C:/Env/localassets/localassets/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Inspecting the `wsgi.py` file I don't see any issues here either.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'localassets.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

It seems as though I am missing something in `wsgi.py` but I am unsure as to what I am missing for this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the apps folder to sys.path in wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Env/localassets')

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'localassets.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

btw. you seem to have the virtual env folder mixed with your app. I would recommend to separate like

```
project_folder
   env
   localassets
      localassets
         wsgi.py

etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes a lot more sense. The django app didn't know where to fetch the apps from. This now works by adding the path above.

Answer (score 0):

In your python environment you have to install the library. You can install projectname with following command:

`pip install projectname` or `pip3 install projectname`
After the installation of projectname python library, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projectname'` error will be solved.
If the error is still there, check your `imports` - you might have to import from either `django_backend` or `user_profile`

Comment: I have updated my question, I used a generic title to reference the projectname but the error thrown states there is no module named 'localassets' i.e. the name of my project. Importing running a pip install for localassets does not fix the error.